Can't see highlight for text selected with cursor in Word 365
I am unable to see the highlight on selected text in Word 365. The text is still selected and can be copied/cut/pasted, but the highlight on the selection is not visible. This problem occurs in both day and dark mode, with and without a black background on the document.
I am able to select/highlight text in other MS 365 apps including Outlook and Excel, as well as Word in Chrome. I can also select/highlight text on websites. I am using the latest version of Firefox on Mac. Below are screenshots of selected text in both backgrounds (note the 'add comment' icon), neither showing the highlight. Any advice on how to resolve this would be appreciated.



Do you have the same issue when using another browser?

I have the same issue on Firefox - started just recently

I have also the same issue on Firefox on a WIndows 10 machine
